# cytoscape.js - add custom svg icon in parent node

Tags: javascript, canvas, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

Hy, I don't find in docs where to add some custom svg elements over parent nodes for eg: like in picture I would like to add a recycle bin icon to the parent node  ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/urrsu.png ) and I don't get it how to achive this.

This is data for cytoscape, and for parent "X" I would like to add

```
  [ { data: { id: 'y' } },
  { data: { id: 'x', name: 'X' } },
  { data: { id: 'a', parent: 'x' } },
  { data: { id: 'b', parent: 'x' } },
  { data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' }}
]
```

Also here is https://codepen.io/crgavrila/pen/wvGXmbe starter

Comment: please try to reformulate the question, I'm having a hard time to understand it.

Comment: Is there a way that I could have access to node context where I can add custom items like a recycle bin like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urrsu.png